# Test class for apex class containing external objects soql query

Tags: unit-test

I wrote a test class for external objects. Since external objects are read only. 
I queried the external object record in test class.
Created a new instance for controller in test class.
When I ran the test class in developer console. It shows the test status as failed & test result as pass for the test method inside the test class. It didn't display any error. And the coverage for the controller is also not displayed. Could anyone advise please?

Comment: Your question is asking for other people to write code for you, without presenting a real question or issue. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you need assistance learning the Salesforce technical environment, I recommend the following resources https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @crmprogdev. Let me edit my question to explain a specific problem about test classes for external objects.